# Benefit from using selector property of the attributes in a WordPress Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a custom Gutenberg block with `attributes` like so:

```js
attributes: {
  title: {
    type: 'string',
    selector: 'js-title'
  },
},
```

Then in my `edit` function, I have a corresponding `RichText` component:

```
<RichText
  className="js-title"
  value={attributes.title}
  onChange={value => setAttributes({ title: value })}
  tagName="h3"
  placeholder="Title"
/>
```

I can leave the `className` portion out of the `RichText` component and the title still saves due to what's specified in `value` and `onChange`.

[WordPress says](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/):

> Each source accepts an optional selector as the first argument. If a selector is specified, the source behavior will be run against the corresponding element(s) contained within the block. Otherwise it will be run against the block’s root node.

But I don't really get what that's saying. Is there any benefit from tying the `RichText` component to the title attribute with a classname?